# Всплывающий label

Tags: php, javascript, css3

На странице есть 2 чекбокса

```
<p><input type="radio" name="RadioBtn" id="RB" value="payeer" /><label for="RB">Payyer</label></p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="RadioBtn" id="RB" value="advcash" /><label for="RB">AdvCash</label></p>
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы при выборе каждого, рядом выскакивал label с каким-то текстом(подсказкой)? Спасибо

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, не допускается использование одного `id` для нескольких элементов. Возможно, Вы забыли поменять содержимое `id` и `for` для второго элемента.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `id` уникально
2. для `for` `label` меняем на соот. id
3. чтобы показать подсказку используем псевдокласс `:checked`

```css
label span {
  display: none;
  color: #f00;
}

[id^=RB]:checked~label span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p><input type="radio" name="RadioBtn" id="RB1" value="payeer"><label for="RB1">Payyer <span>Tooltip</span></label></p>
<p><input type="radio" name="RadioBtn" id="RB2" value="advcash"><label for="RB2">AdvCash <span>Tooltip</span></label></p>
```

Comment: Спасибо! А как можно сделать, чтобы  начальные лейблы payeer и advcash оставались на месте, а при переключении справа допустим добавлялись новые?

Comment: @Midnight Обновил ответ

Comment: То что нужно, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Как один из вариантов:
Присвойте каждому элементу id, и с помощью js или jquery, по событию onclick, прячьте и показывайте контент или блок с информацией.